# Xcode folding: How to make the cursor skip over folded code

Tags: xcode, cursor, fold, skip

I don't know how to word this exactly so Google searches weren't able to help me at all, but when I fold code in Xcode 9 the cursor is actually inside the fold when I navigate through the code, defeating the purpose of me folding in the first place.

How do I make it so that when a portion of code is folded (i.e. a function) the cursor would actually just skip the fold and not actually be inside the fold?

Oh and for context I am using XVim2 with this so idk if this is also an XVim2 issue.